# Crystal Reports convert number to text

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal Reports version 8  and I need to convert a numbervar to stringvar.  I have tried ToText() (with all variations of capitalization) and CStr() (also with various capitalizations) and each time CR tells me "A number is required here" and moves the cursor to the beginning of my else block.  Ultimately trying to convert hours and minutes both stored as NumberVars to strings so I can display "8h 30m" instead of 8.50.

Here is what I have for the formula so far:

```
if {Collect2000Log.LogCode} = "0002" then 0
else 
(
NumberVar OldTime := ((DateDiff("n",{@NextTime},{Collect2000Log.LogWhen})/60)*-1);

NumberVar Hours;
NumberVar Minutes;
StringVar strHours;
StringVar strMinutes;
StringVar NewTime;
//Extract the number of hours
Hours := Int(OldTime);
//Get the decimal portion for minutes
Minutes := Remainder(OldTime, 1) * 100;
//Divide the minutes by 60 to increase the number of hours
Hours := Hours + Int(Minutes / 60);
//Get the remainder for the number of minutes left over
Minutes := Remainder(Minutes, 60);
//Convert hours & mins to strings
strHours := ToText(Hours);
strMinutes := ToText(Minutes):
NewTime := strHours & "h " & strMinutes & "m";
);
```

And now when I add this formula CR says "The end ) is missing" and I'm stumped.  I was able to get around that once but now not looking so hopeful.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is simple... In an `IF` and `Else` you need to return same data type but you are returning a number through `IF` and a String through `Else` hence the error `a Number is required` at the starting of the else block.. so convert the output of `If` to string like below.

```
if {Collect2000Log.LogCode} = "0002" 
then ToText(0)
else 
(
NumberVar OldTime := ((DateDiff("n",{@NextTime},{Collect2000Log.LogWhen})/60)*-1);

NumberVar Hours;
NumberVar Minutes;
StringVar strHours;
StringVar strMinutes;
StringVar NewTime;
//Extract the number of hours
Hours := Int(OldTime);
//Get the decimal portion for minutes
Minutes := Remainder(OldTime, 1) * 100;
//Divide the minutes by 60 to increase the number of hours
Hours := Hours + Int(Minutes / 60);
//Get the remainder for the number of minutes left over
Minutes := Remainder(Minutes, 60);
//Convert hours & mins to strings
strHours := ToText(Hours);
strMinutes := ToText(Minutes):
NewTime := strHours & "h " & strMinutes & "m";
);
```

Comment: Ah, I figured it was something simple! Thank you so much for your help! :)